# Spring: Accessing List of Model Attributes in JSP Dropdown

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

From my controller, I am sending a list of objects to my jsp view. I am using spring form:select tag to make the dropdown which works, but it shows the weird object reference in memory.  How can I get it to just show the name attributes of the objects that I pass in.

```
    <form:form commandName="game">
       <form:select path="name" items="${listOfGames}"></form:select>
    </form:form>
```

This code gives me a drop down of game objects, but I want the dropdown to show the name attribute

Comment: You can use  Map< String, String > listOfGames. In this way, you can use your form as you write above. Value Part of your listOfGames must be the name attributes of the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just use the items attribute as above, spring will try to "stringify" your list/array elements, i.e. call toString() in each of them and since you have not overridden it, the one defined in Object.  An exception to this is whenever you pass a `Map<String, String>` where the keys are used for the value attribute and the values for display.

You have to use the form:options tag properly to explicitly declare which property is used for key and which one for display

```
<form:select path="game">
    <form:options items="${listOfGames}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select>
```

assuming you want to bind the id property

Comment: Awesome, the itemLabel is what I needed to get it work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the problem is because you are not using the options tag.

```
<form:form commandName="game">
   <form:select path="name"> 
       <form:options items="${listOfGames}" />
   </form:select>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS::::**

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="game">
<form:select path="name">
<form:option label="Setect A Game"/>
<form:options items="${listOfGames}"/>
</form:select> 
</form:form>
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your answer showing how your code solves the problem. THis will help others who see your answer in the future